# Should spanish.stackoverflow.com redirect to es.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, languages, language-versions

The standard URL format for non-english Stack Exchange sites is `<language>.stackexchange.com`

- Spanish: [`spanish.stackexchange.com`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)
- Portuguese: [`portuguese.stackexchange.com`](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)
- Japanese: [`japanese.stackexchange.com`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)
- Russian: [`russian.stackexchange.com`](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)

The standard URL format for non-english Stack Overflow sites is `<la>.stackoverflow.com`

- Spanish: [`es.stackoverflow.com`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- Portuguese: [`pt.stackoverflow.com`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- Japanese: [`ja.stackoverflow.com`](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- Russian: [`ru.stackoverflow.com`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

To prevent confusion, should redirects be created for language-specific Stack Overflow communities?

- [`spanish.stackoverflow.com`](https://spanish.stackoverflow.com/) → [`es.stackoverflow.com`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- [`portuguese.stackoverflow.com`](https://portuguese.stackoverflow.com/) → [`pt.stackoverflow.com`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [`japanese.stackoverflow.com`](https://japanese.stackoverflow.com) → [`ja.stackoverflow.com`](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- [`russian.stackoverflow.com`](https://russian.stackoverflow.com) → [`ru.stackoverflow.com`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Is this a substantial problem that would justify the additional expense / complexity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** These language-specific names are in English whereas the two letter language acronym is largely universal. If this were to happen, there would also need to be a redirect for espanol.stackoverflow.com and other localized languages. It adds little value to foreign speakers to have an English named redirect.

Comment: As european I can say most of _us_ are used to universal acronyms for lot of websites, adding a little more of consistency (and no regressions) could be great..

Answer (score -3):

I think, the obvious answer is yes. It is not my interest (my knowledge is zero to very few in any languages for which a non-English SO exists), it is the interest of the StackExchange.

Having a redirect to a site makes it more intuitive to find it, thus it attracts more hits, more visitors. Getting many visitors is obviously an important thing for the company.

While setting up a redirect is a trivial thing.

I don't know, why they doesn't do it. It seems, they have a different opinion and it is their business.

Comment: People don't find websites by typing random things into their URL bar until they find one that works.  People find sites because they're linked to from elsewhere, i.e. Google or other SE sites, in a case like this.  That doesn't mean there isn't ever a reason to have additional redirect links, but ability for users to find the site isn't one of them.

Comment: @Servy Most of the questions is coming from new users. Don't think for ourself. I think most readers of this post knows the list of the non-English SO clones very well, and also knows their URL very well. It is about from the new users, from the new visitors. They are coming sometimes from google, but not always. Often they find the site with google, read an useful answer and then they forget it. And... after they have another problem, they want to come back. The redirects would serve as a help for them, to find the "correct" site (and not, for example, an SO competitor).

Comment: @Servy If a newbie programmer has a problem, he has the intention to ask this on the internet, then he is thinking on a site, where he can find it. *He tries to pull out site names from his mind*. There is a *battle* in his mind, a battle between the SO and its competitors, to let themselfes be remembered first. I think it is *crucial* for any internet site to *win this battle*, that is all.

Comment: So you're arguing that someone is going to come to the site, get a useful answer, then forget all about it, but then type in this new url, letter perfect, into their address bar, without ever having seen it anywhere?  I...frankly don't buy it, at least for any non-trivial number of people.  People don't find new websites by typing in random things into their URL bar and seeing what's there.  They find new sites through web searched, or being directed to them from other sites they visit.

Comment: Having additional redirect urls like these *don't solve that problem*.  They're not urls that people are actually going to be seeing, as they're just going to redirect to the real urls, and they're not things that people actually type out in that situation (they're going to go to a web search, or favorites, or something like that).

Comment: @Servy Ok. You are entitled to your opinion. You are free to think that internet sites don't have to optimize their URLs and redirects to attract new visitors. You are free to construct complex argumentation supporting that. I am sorry that my opinion is a little bit different. I think our rational argumentation ends here.